# open_basedir restriction when running script from command line

Tags: php, apache, command-line

I'm learning how to use the command line by requirement for a recent project. I have a script that will be run during a cronjob, and am testing it by hitting it from the command line using Putty.

My script runs fine from the browser, but from the command line I get permission errors trying to include files or even check if they exist.

This only happens from the command line. This is what is in the console (I'm sure the correct script is executing, and all it does for now is check if a required file exists):

Here is the line in the terminal that executes the command:

> secure:~/www/private/cron$ php -f ./update.php

Here is the output:

> Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
> File(/usr/local/apache/htdocs/example.com/private/modules/real_estate/config/condos.php)
> is not within the allowed path(s):
> (.:/tmp/:/var/tmp/:/usr/local/apache/htdocs/example.com/images/:/home/example/www/images/)
> in /usr/local/apache/htdocs/example.com/private/cron/update.php
> on line 43

I *do not* get this error running the script in a browser, which is confusing to me - but as I mentioned I am new to using the command line. I've tried every way I can think of to reference the file from `update.php`, and tried changing the include path, but nothing seems to work. Either I get the permission error or it can't find the file.

Does anyone know why there is a difference between executing the script in a browser VS the command line, and what I can do to resolve this error? I'm happy to provide more information as requested.

---

#### More information:

This is my CLI output from `php --ini`:

> Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/lib
> Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/Zend/etc/php.ini
> Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
> Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

This is the `Loaded Configuration File` entry in `phpinfo()`, from the browser:

> /usr/local/Zend/etc/php.ini

So `Loaded Configuration File` appears to be the same in both environments.

Comment: Are you using the same php.ini file for both your web server and command line instances?

Comment: a simple way to check both is a) for web, make a quick test page with only `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and check the `Loaded Configuration File` entry; and b) for CLI, enter `php --ini` checking the same entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to run two different php.ini files for CLI vs Apache instances.

One way to do that is to copy your current php.ini file to another directory - say into "/usr/local/Zend/etc/php_cli/php.ini" or a more convenient directory.  Then, change settings in "/usr/local/Zend/etc/php_cli/php.ini" to better suit a command line environment (expand [`open_basedir`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) a bit, log file paths, [and other CLI-specific settings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.differences.php)).  Then, when executing CLI scripts, include the `-c "/usr/local/Zend/etc/php_cli"` switch to have CLI reference *that* ini file.

Comment: I did get confirmation from our server guy that it is an issue on his end that could be fixable without any additional configuration on my end, but I will check this out nonetheless. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I just wanted to pitch in that if you're using `php` via command-line as a server scripting language (i.e - not for web-pages etc.) then you can quickly override this setting with the `-d` option like so: `php -d open_basedir=NULL -r 'touch ($argv[1], $argv[2]);' -- '/tmp/test' $(($(date +%s) - 86400))` this example is handy on systems with broken implementations of `touch`, such as those with older versions of BusyBox. Obviously you don't want to do this in cases where you're handling user input, keep those as restricted as possible.

Comment: @Haravikk your comment should be the actual answer. `-d` worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is often a difference between the php.ini for your server and the php.ini for the command line. This means that whatever you're seeing in the browser is almost certainly not what you'll see when you enter `php -r 'phpinfo();'` on the command line (I mean, the formatting is different and it is less colorful)

You'll want to look for the other php.ini, and then you'll want to commend out `open_basedir = <something>`

Comment: For some reason, output for `php -r 'phpinfo();'` was incomplete, it only showed the tail-end of it. Doesn't seem right, I think I need to find another CLI client or learn how to use Putty more effectively. This was still useful info, thanks.

Comment: @bob You know, I had thought that there was a fast way to do that, but I could only remember the php -r 'phpinfo();' at the time.

Comment: @cwallenpoole: No worries.  Only slight differences in output, but both giving the same information OP needs.